# How to get changed value from one loop to another

Tags: c

I want to get the changed value of a from loop 1 to loop 2. For c programming (i am not printing whole programme)
Edit:
i think i should have write it more clearly so let me give a example let a = 500 and attack be 200 when loop 1 is executed for first time a becomes 300 now i want this value of a =300 to go into loop 2 but in output value 500 is going in for loop 2

```
    for (a= 500; a>= 0;) // loop 1
            {
                a= a- attack;

                printf("Health remaining(Trainer 2) %10d\n", a);
                break;
            }

            for (a; a>= 0;) // loop 2
            {
                printf("Trainer 2 :Enter 1 to commence attack\n");
                scanf("%d", &b);
```

Comment: Why not placing the content of loop 2 inside of loop 1?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio i already tried it but i am not getting the desired result

Comment: We can give you a solution to your problem for sure, but we have too less information and that what you have asked for is not possible. - The question is: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The whole code is kind of too lengthy but let me see if i can provide you full code.And also It is kind of personal project.

Comment: @Achilles73 If you are not planning to file a patent, then you can definitely post here.

Comment: @Achilles73 We don´t need **your** exact code. We need only an example to reproduce the problem. Just showcase your issue one a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio now i have given a example now try it and tell me if you can solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can make your variable `a` as global variable in your c program, and if you change the value of the variable `a` in say Loop 1, then you can just use the same variable name in loop 2 to access the value since the variable is a global variable.

Comment: Really ! Is it necessary to make a value global to use in two loops ? It would be sufficient if it is in the scope of that two for loops ( function or block (``{ }``))

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio How can you deduce ``a`` to be at max ``-1`` after the end of the first for loop ? OP seems to have an unchecked break condition (breaks after the first iteration) . So ``a`` value has an inherent dependency on ``attack`` value.

Comment: @MohithReddy Ah, yes. Missed the `break;`. But nonetheless, OP seems to seek for something completely different.